# Using an SQL Query in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, sql, buffer

I am trying to use arcpy to buffer a file geodatabase feature class and want to set the buffer_distance to the maximum value of a field in a separate dBase table.

My code is:

```
in_features = "projectArea"
out_feature_class = "bufferedProjectArea"
buffer_distance = (SELECT MAX("Distance") FROM "distanceTable")
line_side = "FULL"
line_end_type = "ROUND"
dissolve_option = "ALL"

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features, out_feature_class, buffer_distance, line_side, line_end_type, dissolve_option)
```

My distanceTable is a dbase table (.dbf) looks like this:

```
OBJECTID    Type     Distance
1          Raccoons  2100
2          Squirrels 0
12         Cities    4200
```

I am trying to buffer by the maximum value in the distance field of my distanceTable. In this case it is cities, but I want to make the code robust so that when I change the values, the buffer distance is still pointing to the max value. I am receiving generic "syntax error" and am looking for assistance for the proper SQL code to replace for:

```
buffer_distance = (SELECT MAX("Distance") FROM "distanceTable")
```

Comment: Yes the line `buffer_distance = (SELECT MAX("Distance") FROM "distanceTable")` is not valid syntax

Comment: It's not valid Python syntax, and a SQL subquery is not applicable to a dBase table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a cursor to find the max distance. Then apply the distance to your buffer.

```
in_features = "projectArea"
out_feature_class = "bufferedProjectArea"
line_side = "FULL"
line_end_type = "ROUND"
dissolve_option = "ALL"

#set buffer distance to None
buffer_distance = None
#create cursor
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor ("distanceTable", "Distance") as curs:
    #iterate cursor
    for dist, in curs:
        #check if value is greater than current greatest value
        #update if greater
        if dist > buffer_distance: buffer_distance = dist

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features, out_feature_class, buffer_distance, line_side, line_end_type, dissolve_option)
```

You can also make use of a numpy array:

```
in_features = "projectArea"
out_feature_class = "bufferedProjectArea"
line_side = "FULL"
line_end_type = "ROUND"
dissolve_option = "ALL"

#get max value
buffer_distance = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray ("distanceTable", "Distance")["Distance"].max ()

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features, out_feature_class, buffer_distance, line_side, line_end_type, dissolve_option)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to convert the table to a `numpy` array:

```
import numpy
...
np = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("distanceTable", ["Distance"])
buffer_distance= np["Distance"].max()
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you would benefit from a function return to accomplish it....but this is for clarity more than for efficiency

```
import arcpy, dbf
def get_max_value(afield_name, my_dbf_table):
   ## open the table and loop through values
  db = dbf.Dbf(my_dbf_table)
  biggest_value = 0
  for rec in db:
    if rec[afield_name] > biggest_value:
      biggest_value = rec[afield_name]

  return biggest_value


## Now I can buffer....
in_features = "projectArea"
out_feature_class = "bufferedProjectArea"
buffer_distance = get_max_value("Distance","distanceTable")
line_side = "FULL"
line_end_type = "ROUND"
dissolve_option = "ALL"

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(.....)
```